# How to have one Auto Incremented id for two separate tables in mysql?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, sequence

I have 2 different tables, each having its own id column.

I need that if one table is using a specific id, the other table will not use it. This is needed because the object in both tables will later be handled **together** by another component in the application, and the other component must have them uniquely identified by the id.

I thought to have a table `counter` with `next_id` column, and have a `before insert trigger` to each of these tables, that will take the current id from `counter`, use it for the new row, and increase it.

My question is, is this synchronized? i.e. what will happen if 2 different applications, or threads in a single application, insert columns to any of these tables?

Do I have to lock the counter table during the trigger? If yes, will it be locked until the end of the entire transaction, or just until the trigger ends?

Is there a better solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two tables share ID space, surely then they should have a common parent table?

I would create a parent table and make the two other tables children of it with foreign keys. The parent has the autoincrement field, and you have to insert there first before inserting the child. Add a "type" column to the parent table so you know in which table to look for the child with the given ID.

The biggest advantage to this approach is that you don't need any triggers. No performance or synchronicity problems to worry about.

In PostgreSQL you would implement this using inheritance, but I don't think MySQL has this feature.

Comment: If I don't have any other way I'll add a parent table. If it's not for the ids generation, it's really not needed.

Comment: I'd argue that it *is* needed because the tables share the same ID-space.

Comment: They share the same id space due to a restriction unrelated directly to the database.
From my app point of view, they are completely different objects.

Comment: Dikla, I agree with @Colin'tHart. It is needed because (your words) *"both tables will later be handled together by another component in the application"*. Items in both tables are seen as one type of object by (that component of) your application.

Comment: It's a completely separate component, it doesn't even read the data from the database.

Comment: Although I hoped for another answer (something similar to a sequence in PostgreSQL would have solved the problem very easily), I'm accepting this answer, since no better ones were given.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to create a table like this

```
Create Table RelationTable
(
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    report_id INT UNSIGNED,
    reportType TINYINT
);
```

WHERE

- id = unique id
- report_id = unique id in table1 or table2
- reportType = 1 for table1 and 2 for table2

now insert your data into table1 and table2 and then insert the id and type into relation Table

Comment: I don't understand your solution. 1) You have no unique constraint on `report_id`. 2) Your solution doesn't solve the problem how to generate the IDs for the two tables in question. 3) You suggest a very strange order of insertion. Surely it's  better to first insert in this table and *then* insert into the real table as this table can be seen as the parent of the other two. 4) Why have the column `id` primary key when `report_id` should also be unique?

Comment: Why have the column `id` anyway? Totally useless it seems.

Comment: I think that he means that table1 and table2 manage their own id by auto increment, and each record from these tables will also have a record in the relation table. It's actually maintaining 3 sets of IDs... Better having it the other way round, like Colin 't Hart suggested. Thanks anyway, Masoud.

Comment: @Dikla you got me right. The unique id u need in this structure is the combination of `report_id` and `reportType`. @ypercube is also right. The id column is not needed. I put it there so u have a unique id for any of your records just in case u need a fast look up instead of indexing the other two columns. @colin the insertion order is not strange. he need to insert to main table first to get their unique (for that table) id and then the reference can be inserted into the relation table. if i reverse the order, it will become your suggestion.